# meteor JS: why pictures are reversed and how to make onclick reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, reverse, photo

I'm learning to make basic site for adding photos, and when I add pictures   they are upside down. I have no idea how to reverse them. When I open them in photo gallery they are normal, not reversed, also when I open photo in paint and  not doing anything (because its not reversed) I save it, then photos become normal on a website.
I couldn't fix that so I tried adding package with jQueryReverse plugin:
meteor add jjman505:jquery-rotate ,
 to reverse pictures using button below images, but this option is still not working for me. 
I have no idea what I did wrong and how to work it out, so I hope you can help me. I guess it's something basic I must have missed.

HTML:

```
 <body>
        <div class="container">
    {{> images}}
        </div>
</body>
    <template name="images">

    <div class="row">
        {{#each images}}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" id="{{_id}}">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="js-image" src="{{img_src}}" alt="{{img_alt}}"/>
            <div class="caption">
            <button class="btn btn-info js-rotate-image">rotate </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    </template>
```

JS:

```
Images= new Mongo.Collection("images");
if (Meteor.isClient){ 


    Template.images.helpers({images:
        Images.find({}, {sort:{createdOn: -1, rating: -1}})

});

    Template.images.events({
'click .js-rotate-image':function(event){
            var image_id = this._id;
            console.log(image_id);
            $("#"+image_id).rotateLeft([angle=90]);

        }
    });
```

startup.js:

```
if (Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.startup(function(){
        if (Images.find().count() == 0){        
            for (var i=1;i<22;i++){
                Images.insert(
                    {
                    img_src:"img_"+i+".jpg",
                    img_alt:"image number "+i 
                    }
                );  
            }
```

I also tried. `rotate(90)` but didn't work as well.
I cut the code, but I hope I didn't cut anything important in solving that problem.
Thanks

Comment: I was unable to find jQueryReverse but the syntax `rotateLeft([angle=90])` looks a little strange.  Does `rotateLeft` accept an array and do you mean to assign `angle` the value 90?

Answer (score 0):

Use this package. It is happening because of metadata image have.

https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-clientside-image-manipulation